# SO sorry, i did not know this spot was reserved

Tags: support

I thought this was a venue where people could share ideas, help people with questions, and generally contribute.

Unfortunately, I find that this is not a friendly playground. NO, the traditional playground bully is out and active.

I am not here for a fight, so..

Congratulations, L.Dutch. You have managed to bully me away.
Enjoy your victory, though god knows why you feel such confrontation is necessary.

Adios.

Answer (score 10):

Since you're throwing accusations of bullying, let's have a look at this alleged bullying.

Our [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) explains how to answer:

> Answer the question
>
> Read the question carefully. What, specifically, is the question asking for? Make sure your answer provides that – or a viable alternative.

1. I pointed out that a part of your [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/190418/30492) was addressing a
   question that was not asked.
2. I pointed out that you were giving a non-[hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science)
   [answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/190227/30492) to a question tagged [hard-science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-science).

You call it bullying. In my book that's called "a request to follow the community standards".

And as Ash made clear in their [answer](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8123/30492), you have deleted those answers out of your own will.

Comment: After looking through the comment and answer edit chains, I can't see that you did anything impolite (much less bullying...). Hopefully MarvinKitFox (user79911?) is willing to take a deep breath and work with us. It does take a bit to get used to the fact that Stack Exchange has fairly rigid System-wide and Stack-wide rules.

Comment: MarvinKitFox? Who's he?

Comment: @TheDaleks Both accounts have been deleted. I'm pretty sure user79911 was MarvinKitFox before his temper tantrum and user80772 was MarvinKitFox. I wrote my comments before the second account was deleted.

Answer (score 8):

> I thought this was a venue where people could share ideas, help people with questions, and generally contribute.

Yes. Yes, it is. There are site rules (coming from Stack Exchange) and forum rules that guide how the sharing of ideas happens. There are also general standards of online & interpersonal behavior that the community expects of its participants, whether those standards are written or not.

> Unfortunately, I find that this is not a friendly playground. NO, the traditional playground bully is out and active.

> Congratulations, L.Dutch. You have managed to bully me away. Enjoy your victory, though god knows why you feel such confrontation is necessary.

> Sorry. again, the gods do not approve of my answers. Apologies.

Well, you brought your own unfriendliness with you.  These are fine examples of community standards that we can reasonably expect you to adhere to, regardless of where you go online. You are behaving like a passive-aggressive & self-centered 10 year old. Your behavior is petulant, overly dramatic, and needlessly pointless.

Kudos if you actually are 10 years old, because then you're only behaving your age!  Otherwise, we really don't need this kind of aggressive behavior from you. If you can't behave in Main in a reasonably adult manner and if you can't address your concerns here in Meta without resorting to a temper tantrum, then please, by all means go somewhere else.

I'd invite you to go away, but it looks like you're already gone, so thank you at the least for improving the quality of our user base with your absence!

Answer (score 7):

*Now I say this as someone who conflicts with the mods fairly often:*

L Dutch did not delete your question, but instead raised a critique on it.

1. You then deleted all the text leaving a stub.
2. Then you deleted your own answer.
3. L.Dutch then undeleted your answer.
4. Then L.Dutch rolled the answer history back to your original answer.

Here's the proof:

[image]

Your answer was pretty informative and I liked it. I upvoted it. And - meh - the second half of your text went off topic - not a big deal (I do that all the time). I thought it was an interesting observation even if it was off topic.

Comment: *"Now I say this as someone who conflicts with the mods fairly often"*. Hehehe, that's funny.

Comment: we should fix that *next election*. If he's a mod, he can't conflict with mods anymore ;)